# Dummy variables to control for clustering

Tags: clustering, categorical-data, econometrics, standard-error

I have a panel-data sample which is not too large (1,973 observations). The unit of analysis is x (credit cards), which is grouped by y (say, individuals owning different credit cards). I cannot used fixed effects because I have important dummy variables, and random effects is inadequate. Therefore, I am using OLS. To control clustering in y, I have introduced a dummy variable for each y. My question is whether this is fine, i.e., whether clustering is taken into consideration this way (instead of using straightforward y-clustered errors).

Comment: If random effects is inadequate then so is pooled OLS. A cluster dummy in the regression will not correct the standard errors so if this is the aim you need to use the cluster-robust standard errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Andy. I said that I cannot use random effects because I can hardly state that the individual-specific error is uncorrelated with the regressors. As regards your second statement, could you be a bit more explicit? If I am not mistaken, a dummy variable for each y is similar to adding a fixed-effect term which would control clustering.

Comment: Random effects and OLS have basically the same assumptions for giving you consistent estimates. If the Hausman test rejects random effects that means that also OLS is likely to be inconsistent. If you want to account for clustering in your standard errors the individual dummies won't help (and yes, it would be a fixed effects regression). These dummies give you individual specific intercepts but they do not account for clustering of the errors within individual - and this is what you wanted, right?

Comment: What is your dependent and what are the explanatory variables actually? It would be helpful if you could write down the model you are estimating so to understand what is the goal here. This allows to provide a better answer.

Comment: Thanks, Andy. Since I read your comment, I have been trying to figure out what I should do. This is (a simplified version) of the model (at this point): use = rate + dquarter* + dindividual*, where use is the level of use of a credit card (ie, card is the unit of analysis), dquarter* are dummies of quarter, and dindividual* are dummies for individual. And the idea is whether dindividual* is enough o cluster(individual) is necessary.

Comment: As regards my question, I have also found the argument that the advantage of using dummies (instead of cluster()) is that it allows for differences in the average level of across individuals in addition to adjusting the standard errors taking into account the specific intra-group correlation. Does it make sense?

Comment: Ok Miguel, I think this is enough information to answer your question. I have attempted this below and hope you'll find it useful. If there is anything else that is unclear please feel free to ask for clarification :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are estimating an equation like
$$\text{use}_{jit} = \beta \text{rate}_{jit} + \text{quarter}_t \delta + \text{individual}_i\gamma + \epsilon_{ijt}$$
where $\text{use}_{jit}$ is the usage of credit card $j$ at time $t$ owned by individual $i$, and $\text{quarter}_t$ and $\text{individual}_i$ are sets of time and individual dummies. You are worried that credit cards owned by the same individual have common shocks/errors, which makes sense. Let me give you a quick refresher on clustered standard errors and then I will address your question regarding the benefits of having group dummies to account for clustering.

For the moment forget about the time component for simplicity. If you didn't include your individual dummies the error would be a composite of the individual error (the group error) and the card level error, $\epsilon_{ij} = \nu_{i} + \eta_{ij}$. With such an error structure your intraclass correlation is then $\rho = \frac{\sigma^2_\nu}{\sigma^2_\nu + \sigma^2_\eta}$. Comparing the variances of the usual standard error and the cluster-robust standard error (clustered at the individual level) you would get
$$\frac{Var^{clust}(\widehat{\beta})}{Var^{ols}(\widehat{\beta})} = 1 + (n-1)\rho $$
which would tell you by how much the usual standard errors overestimate precision by ignoring the within group correlation (see for instance slide 17 and 18 of these [notes](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/soc/economics/staff/ffwaldinger/teaching/ec9a8/slides/lecture_5_-_mixed.pdf)).

If you include individual dummies, i.e. individual fixed effects, this would address the problem. In that case you cannot include any time-invariant control variables at the individual level though. This only works if your control variables are at an aggregate level (here at the individual level). For this see page 8 bullet point 3 in these [notes](http://kurt.schmidheiny.name/teaching/clustering2up.pdf). However, the usage of credit cards of the same individual is probably very highly correlated. In this situation the individual dummies will take out too much information in which case it is better to not use those dummies but still the errors would need to be adjusted. That's bullet point four in the same notes. Correcting the errors is easily done by estimating the usual cluster-robust standard errors clustering at the individual level.

Another advantage of the clustered standard errors is the time component. Clustering at the individual level will not only allow for within individual correlation of the credit card usage, it will also account for heteroscedasticity between individuals and it will correct for serial correlation. Given that you have a time component serial correlation may be an issue. The error of an individual yesterday is likely to be correlated with the error of the same individual today - simply because she is the same person with the same habits, shocks, etc.

Long story short: your way works under certain assumptions. The more flexible standard error correction is to estimate cluster-robust standard errors.

Comment: To be sure that I get you (and the linked notes) right: What does exactly mean to be an "aggregate" variable on the level of the cluster (page 8 bullet points 2 and 3)? Does it mean that a variable refers to (in my case) the individual? If this is correct, bullet point 2 would state that using individual fixed effects is advised if ONLY control variables refer to the individual. However, bullet point 3 states that this method is not to be used if the usage of credit cards does not refer to the individual. Is not there a contradiction? Does bullet point 3 dominate bullet point 2?

Comment: Your individual is the cluster level so an aggregate variable for the credit cards would be individual income (since this determines the cards maximum withdrawal amount or debit). If you have credit card level data (e.g. total amount of money available per card) for point 2 you would need to sum that (collapse) information. Point 3 concerns the case where you have individual information on the cards like the income example. The main point here was that the dummies will not do anything about heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation as well.